# ¿Crear un JSON a partir de una consulta MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, json

```
function connectDB(){

   $conexion = mysqli_connect("servidor", "usuario", "contraseña", "base de datos");
    if($conexion){
        echo 'La conexión de la base de datos se ha hecho satisfactoriamente
';
    }else{
        echo 'Ha sucedido un error inesperado en la conexión de la base de datos
';
    }   
    return $conexion;
}
```

Es mi código base para hacer la conexión a la base de datos.

Aunque, no sé exactamente cómo hacer para seleccionar la tabla de donde se obtendrán los datos.

Tengo éste otro que usé en un proyecto a parte, pero no sé si sea válido para esto que quiero hacer, puesto que aún no entiendo muy bien cómo hacerlo, por ende no he realizado pruebas:

```
$nick = urlencode($_GET['nick']);
mysql_select_db("statistiques", $link);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM player WHERE name='".$nick."'", $link);
```

Lo que quiero hacer se resume más o menos en estos tutoriales:

[Creación de un JSON a partir de una consulta en MySQL.](https://geekytheory.com/json-ii-creacion-de-un-json-a-partir-de-una-consulta-en-mysql/)

[Gestionar JSON en PHP.](https://geekytheory.com/json-iii-gestionar-json-en-php/)

Pero aún no me queda claro como hacer todo eso y no entiendo muy bien el tutorial.

Dentro de la tabla `statistiques`, existe otra llamada `player`. Cuyos datos que quiero establecer para que otros puedan realizar [consultas a partir de mi archivo son](https://geekytheory.com/json-iv-ejemplo-practico-de-uso-de-json-con-openweathermap/):

`id, name, title, experience, first, bootcamp, round_played, shaman_cheese, saved_mice, saved_mice_hard, saved_mice_divine, cheese_gathered`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responderé a la pregunta en el título utilizando la consulta que dejas de ejemplo porque en el post no te he entendido bien.

Esta es la consulta de tu post actualizada a MySQLi y filtrando el nick para evitar inyecciones SQL que destruyan tu base de datos:

```
$nick = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['nick']);
mysqli_select_db($link, 'statistiques');
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM player WHERE name = '{$nick}'");
```

Para exportar los datos de esta consulta a JSON lo primero que tenemos que hacer es pasar los datos devueltos a un array:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) $array[] = $row;
```

Y el siguiente paso es utilizar la función json_encode() para convertir ese array a  JSON:

```
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Con estos dos pasos ya tienes el JSON guardado en la variable $json en forma de string.